# Not able call the external HTTP APIs throungh Android App

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created an android app by a capacitor, But I can not able to access the HTTP APIs through the Android Studio Emulator,

I have changed my files like this:

build.gradle(:app)

```
     android {
            compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
           defaultConfig {
             applicationId "com.app.net"
             minSdkVersion 24
             targetSdkVersion 28
             versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
             }
          buildTypes {
             release {
                minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
          }
    }
```

I have created new file app/res/xml

network_security_config.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <network-security-config>
          <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
                 <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://prod- 
                                     ********.***asia.cloudapp.azure.com</domain>
           </domain-config>
        </network-security-config>
```

then I have modified:

AndroidMainfest.xml

```
     <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

After making these changes yesterday it worked but not now. I don't no the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to only include domain in the `<domain>...</domain>` tag (without the http://) like so:

```
<domain includeSubdomains="true">prod-********.***asia.cloudapp.azure.com</domain>
```